# Download the zip from url, count number of files in zip file and send the download success and file count string to response body

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am new to api development and developing the api to download the zip file from the url.

Where I need to read the file count (i.e.the number of files in the zip file) and send the count to response body and also at the same time Download the zip.

I am able to download the zip but parallel to that I am not able to send the count to response body,

I have searched on internet for same problem but nobody have solutions.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Hello  Nikolay Shevchenko thats what I am asking. I am not able to find how to download file and at the same time send the success as response body. Please tell if this is doable or not?

Comment: "Please tell if this is doable or not". It sounds do-able. But the question is perhaps a bit too vague to be able to provide a good and to the point answer. I think maybe you should break your problem into smaller sub-problems and try to solve them one at a time. E.g. problem 1: how to write a simple server than handles http requests. Problem 2: how to send/receive large binary data in http request. Problem 3: how to read zip data using Java 'ZipInputStream' API. If you answer all 3 questions then yu have to figure out how to put it all together in a single program.

Comment: Hey @Kris I am not at all asking the que you have listed, Please read it again and provide the solution if you can.  Also what you have listed is achieved before posting the que.

Comment: @shilpa, I am sorry if that wasn't helpful to you. It is how I understood what you were asking though. To be honest, if what I was saying is not relevant, then I don't think I understand your question at all and won't be able to help you. Similarly, I think, will be the case for other people. So maybe try and rephrase your question a bit and try make it more clear what it is you are really asking here.